# deploying to gcloud produces horrific build error

Tags: gcloud

Long story short, I am deploying a django app to app engine. The build process appears to install many packages and then errors out, like so.

Edit. This is the (redacted) build log. The command line output of `gcloud app deploy` is located below.

```
(((redacted, everything up to this point builds successfully)))
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: pip_install_from_wheels
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --no-deps --prefix /tmp/tmp1IKuwt/env /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/aldryn_apphooks_config-0.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl --disable-pip-version-check
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_install_from_wheels` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": Processing /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/aldryn_apphooks_config-0.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Step #1 - "builder": Installing collected packages: aldryn-apphooks-config
Step #1 - "builder": Successfully installed aldryn-apphooks-config-0.5.3
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: pip_install_from_wheels
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --no-deps --prefix /tmp/tmpwuKmD2/env /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/cryptography-2.8-cp34-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl --disable-pip-version-check
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_install_from_wheels` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": Processing /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/cryptography-2.8-cp34-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
Step #1 - "builder": Installing collected packages: cryptography
Step #1 - "builder": Successfully installed cryptography-2.8
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: pip_install_from_wheels
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --no-deps --prefix /tmp/tmp85xugM/env /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl --disable-pip-version-check
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_install_from_wheels` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": Processing /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Step #1 - "builder": Installing collected packages: gunicorn
Step #1 - "builder": Successfully installed gunicorn-20.0.4
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_install_from_wheels` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder":   WARNING: The script gunicorn is installed in '/tmp/tmp85xugM/env/bin' which is not on PATH.
Step #1 - "builder":   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: pip_install_from_wheels
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --no-deps --prefix /tmp/tmpwrJu3c/env /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl --disable-pip-version-check
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_install_from_wheels` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": Processing /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Step #1 - "builder": Installing collected packages: pycparser
Step #1 - "builder": Successfully installed pycparser-2.19
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: pip_install_from_wheels
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --no-deps --prefix /tmp/tmpnObJ5s/env /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/queuelib-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl --disable-pip-version-check
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_install_from_wheels` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": Processing /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/queuelib-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Step #1 - "builder": Installing collected packages: queuelib
Step #1 - "builder": Successfully installed queuelib-1.5.0
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: pip_install_from_wheels
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --no-deps --prefix /tmp/tmpPvXJiN/env /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/tzlocal-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl --disable-pip-version-check
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_install_from_wheels` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": Processing /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/tzlocal-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Step #1 - "builder": Installing collected packages: tzlocal
Step #1 - "builder": Successfully installed tzlocal-2.0.0
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: pip_install_from_wheels
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --no-deps --prefix /tmp/tmpVNLN0Z/env /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/pip-20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl --disable-pip-version-check
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_install_from_wheels` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": Processing /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/pip-20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Step #1 - "builder": Installing collected packages: pip
Step #1 - "builder":   Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
Step #1 - "builder":     Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
Step #1 - "builder":       Successfully uninstalled pip-19.2.3
Step #1 - "builder": Successfully installed pip-20.1
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels took 1 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: pip_install_from_wheels
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --no-deps --prefix /tmp/tmptNKyMq/env /tmp/tmpDGYffm/wheel/pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl --disable-pip-version-check
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_install_from_wheels` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_install_from_wheels` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder": /env/bin/python3.7: No module named pip
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    error: `pip_install_from_wheels` returned code: 1
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_install_from_wheels took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     build process for FTL image took 45 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     full build took 45 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    `pip_install_from_wheels` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder": /env/bin/python3.7: No module named pip
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": error: `pip_install_from_wheels` returned code: 1
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder":     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder":     exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 60, in main
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_error.py", line 77, in InternalErrorHandler
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37_app_builder:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

As  you can see, this is very perplexing. `/env/bin/python3.7: No module named pip`? seems like a problem in the app engine build process.

Here is the output of the command `gcloud app deploy`.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 168573b7-17ed-4bb8-a92d-8cdf7b9ca751 status: FAILURE.                                                          Build error details: {
{
    "error": {
        "errorType": "BuildError",
        "canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "errorId": "D2E1945E",
        "errorMessage": "14 May 2020 04:28:03 INFO     Arguments: ['--parser_script=/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--src=', '--entrypoint=', '--name=us.gcr.io/gae-cms-277200/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:b073c253-b4db-4dbf-afef-0bd8a2ac8ccc', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=us.gcr.io/gae-cms-277200/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00']\n14 May 2020 04:28:03 INFO     Unparsed arguments: ['--name=us.gcr.io/gae-cms-277200/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:b073c253-b4db-4dbf-afef-0bd8a2ac8ccc', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=us.gcr.io/gae-cms-277200/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00']\n14 May 2020 04:28:03 INFO     Executing ['/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--name=us.gcr.io/gae-cms-277200/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:b073c253-b4db-4dbf-afef-0bd8a2ac8ccc', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=us.gcr.io/gae-cms-277200/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00']\nINFO     FTL version python-v0.17.0\nINFO     Beginning FTL build for python\nINFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_dir /env\nINFO     FTL arg passed: ttl 168\nINFO     FTL arg passed: python_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_cmd virtualenv\nINFO     FTL arg passed: entrypoint None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: exposed_ports None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: pip_cmd /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip\nINFO     FTL arg passed: tar_base_image_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: export_cache_stats False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: builder_output_path \"\"\nINFO     FTL arg passed: destination_path /srv\nINFO     FTL arg passed: sh_c_prefix False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: base us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.17.0\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_salt \nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_repository us.gcr.io/gae-cms-277200/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d\nINFO     FTL arg passed: venv_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env\nINFO     FTL arg passed: name us.gcr.io/gae-cms-277200/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:b073c253-b4db-4dbf-afef-0bd8a2ac8ccc\nINFO     FTL arg passed: global_cache False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: upload True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: output_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: directory /workspace\nINFO     FTL arg passed: additional_directory /.googleconfig\nINFO     FTL arg passed: verbosity DEBUG\nINFO     starting: full build\nINFO     starting: builder initialization\nINFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00'\nINFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'us.gcr.io/gae-cms-277200/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:b073c253-b4db-4dbf-afef-0bd8a2ac8ccc'\nINFO     builder initialization took 0 seconds\nINFO     starting: build process for FTL image\nINFO     starting: checking_cached_interpreter_layer\nINFO     starting: check python version\nINFO     `python version` full cmd:\n/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 --version\nINFO     `python version` stderr:\n\nINFO     check pyt."
    }
}
```

Edit. Sorry about the formatting on that error message!

Any suggestions as to how to debug this problem would be very much appreciated.

Edit. I believe the solution is to upgrade from python 36 to 37, as described in `app.yaml`. I will keep working and post an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not see your `requirements.txt` file, but this problem has already appeared.
If you take a look [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/485) and [here](https://safecontrols.blog/2019/01/), you will find resolutions. I know they are outdated however if you take similar approach you should easily deal with it.

I hope it will help!